# difference between to be related to and to relate to

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs, differences

What is the correct way to say? Are both variants possible?

1. Basque, the language which is spoken in northwestern Spain and southwestern France, does not relate to any other language in the world.
2. Basque, the language which is spoken in northwestern Spain and southwestern France, is not related to any other language in the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/relate-to) recognises that 'relate to' is more cohesive than the usual 'verb and preposition[al phrase]' string, though it is debatable whether most would call it a 'phrasal verb':

> **relate to** [phrasal verb; transitive]
>
> - 1 (*relate to something*) to be about something, or to be connected with something
>
>   - *We’re only interested in events that relate directly to the murder.*
>   - *We need to see figures relating to the last six months.*
> - 2 (*relate to someone/something*) to be able to understand a situation or the way that someone feels and thinks
>
>   - *Martin had always found it easier to relate to women.*
>   - *The programme deals with scientific subjects that ordinary people can relate to.*

It is possibly the fact that the second usage here is so commonly used that makes the use of your first example sound a little jarring, though it is not unacceptable. Note also that in the examples Macmillan gives under sense '1', 'relate' may be substituted by 'apply'/'pertain', and '[that] refer', respectively, which doesn't work with your sentence.

Your second variant is totally idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very useful.